# Reshape a 3d array to a 2d array with leading points

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to reshape this array (Python)

```
[[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]]
```

To this:

```
[
[0,0,0],
[1,1,1],
[2,2,2],
[3,3,3],
[4,4,4],
[5,5,5],
[6,6,6],
[7,7,7],
[8,8,8],
]
```

and then back.

I couldn't figure out how to do it with `np.reshape`.

It's a series of height maps, and I want to interpolate each point with the corresponding one on the next map to create a smooth transition between them.

Comment: An example is good. But you also need to explain the logic. As written, it is unclear how we should go from your input to your output. Especially considering the `[3,3,3]` in your output when there is not a single `3` in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With last correction, it seems that what you want is something like

```py
np.moveaxis(a, 0,-1).reshape(-1,3)
```

Result

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

You probably know how to use `reshape`. It reinterprets the data as an array of as many lines as needed and 3 columns. The reason why `reshape` alone won't do exactly what you want is because you would need the 0s to be consecutive in memory, then the 1s then the 2s, ... Which they are not.
But that is solved by `moveaxis`: those 0s, 1s, 2s, ... are consecutive when you iterate along axis 0 of your input array. So all you have to do is move axis 0 to the end, so that iterating the last axis does that (visiting 0s, then 1s, then 2s, ...).

Note that `moveaxis` is very fast. Because it does not really build a new array. It is just a different view of the existing array. Some tricks with strides, so that visiting order appears changed.

Since you also asked for the other way, here it is (but it is just the same 2 operations, reversed and in reverse order. So undo the reshape, then undo the move axis)

```py
res=np.moveaxis(a, 0,-1).reshape(-1,3) # Just to start from here
np.moveaxis(res.reshape(-1,3,3), -1, 0)
```

Result

```
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
```

as expected

Comment: Note: some timings consideration: for the 3 rows example, both itertools based solutions takes 30 μs, moveaxis/vstack, 20 μs, moveaxis/reshape 10 μs. Difference between itertools based solution and moveaxis based solutions shows of course for larger data, since for small data what we measure is mainly overhead. For example, for 1000 rows, both itertools based solutions take 6 ms, when moveaxis/vstack takes 66 μs, and moveaxis/reshape takes 28 μs. For a sufficient number of rows, once overhead is negligible, it is clear that all 3 solutions are O(n).

Comment: But with a times >100 factor in favor of moveaxis based solutions. For 10000 rows, 65 ms, 477 μs and 169 μs respectively. It also becomes clearer and clearer that among the 2 moveaxis based solutions, there is a factor 2/3 in favor of `reshape` vs `vstack`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]]
)
b = np.vstack(np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2))
```

Reverse operation:

```
a2 = np.moveaxis(np.vsplit(b, 3), 2, 0)
```

I think the easiest way to understand how this works is to look at the examples for [`vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html#numpy.vstack) and then figuring out how do we need to modify array `a` so that `vstack` can produce the desired output.

In this case,

```
>>> np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2)
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]],

       [[7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8],
        [9, 9, 9]]])
```

prepares the array `a` in such a way that now `vstack` can simply "stack" (glue? concatenate?) the 3 "sub-arrays" on top of each other, producing the desired 2D array.

---

##### EDIT: Second solution and Timings

This solution is an order of magnitude faster than any previous solution:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(
    [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
     [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]]
)
b = a.reshape(3, -1).T
```

and for reverse:

```
a2 = b.T.reshape(3, 3, -1)
```

Some timings:

- This solution:

  ```
    In [3]: %timeit a.reshape(3, -1).T
    277 ns ± 7.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
  ```
- My previous solution (`vstack` and `moveaxis`):

  ```
    In [4]: %timeit np.vstack(np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2))
    9.56 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
  ```
- @chrsig's solution (`reshape` and `moveaxis`):

  ```
    In [5]: %timeit np.moveaxis(a, 0,-1).reshape(-1,3)
    3.83 µs ± 147 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
  ```
- @chrsig's 2nd solution (stride tricks):

  ```
    In [6]: %timeit np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(len(a)*len(a[0]), 3), strides=(a.strides[2], a.strides[0]))
    4.38 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
  ```

Comment: Thanks that works! how do I also do the reverse?

Comment: @AGN Gazer can you explain how this works?

Comment: @ACarter It's magic

Comment: @Simon, You are right: it's magic

Answer (score 0):

Another answer (it is rare that I post 2 answers to the same question. But this is really a different answer, and it is not obvious which one is the best, so I think both deserve their own independent post) is to rely on `stride_tricks`. It is a little bit what `moveaxis` already does. But not `reshape`.

A numpy array is just a bunch of data in memory. That are iterated with a given memory offset for each axis. Called `stride`.

For example

```py
a=np.array([[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]])
```

is, internally, a memory array with integers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2,...
And to iterate them we use `strides`

```py
a.strides
# (72, 24, 8)
```

Meaning that `a[i+1,j,k]` is 72 bytes after `a[i,j,k]`, that `a[i,j+1,k]` is 24 bytes after `a[i,j,k]` and `a[i,j,k+1]` is 8 bytes after `a[i,j,k]`.

Or, said otherwise, that `a[i,j,k]` is at address `72*i+24*j+8*k`

Usually data are just contiguous, so strides is just 8 for the last axis (when data are 64 bits integers), 8*3 for the axis before, because there are 3 of those 8 bytes integer per elements of 2nd axis, and 8*3*3 for the first.

But you can have arrays with different strides. That is what happens with moveaxis

```py
np.moveaxis(a, 0, 2).strides
# (24, 8, 72)
```

That is even all what `moveaxis` does: just change the strides so that `np.moveaxis(a,0,2)[i,j,k]` is at memory `24*i+8*j+72*k` in other words, where `a[k,i,j]` is.

Numpy provides lower level function `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to manipulate those strides as we want (not just moving them as with `moveaxis`).

Equivalent of that `np.moveaxis` for example is

```py
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, strides=(24,8,72))
```

We can force that result to be a 2d array, like this

```py
res = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(len(a)*len(a[0]), 3), strides=(a.strides[2], a.strides[0]))
```

One limitation for that: it works only if `a` is a contiguous array (that is, if a is not already a result of some strides manipulation).

One advantage: it is not a new array. No new memory is used here. `res` is just the same as `a`, viewed differently.

In our case result is

```py
>>> res
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8]])
```

But here, you don't need to go back and forth. Those two visions of the data designate the same array.

So for example, if you change

```py
res[0,1]=12
a[1,2,2]=15
```

Both operations impact both arrays

```py
>>>a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[12,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7, 15]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]]])
```

As you see, `a[1,2,2]` is now `15` as it should. But also `a[1,0,0]` (that is what was the 2nd 0) is now 12.

Likewise

```py
>>> b
array([[ 0, 12,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [ 3,  3,  3],
       [ 4,  4,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 7,  7,  7],
       [ 8, 15,  8]])
```

`b[0,1]` is now `12`, as expected. But also `b[8,1]` is now 15.

So don't know if this is useful for you. But I suspect it might, since you wanted to be able to go back and forth both format. With this, no need to. You can have them both at the same time, without conversion, without building arrays.

And of course, that is even faster than `moveaxis/reshape`

So, tl;dr:

If having two views of the same array is ok for you, and if `a` is a contiguous array (not something that you obtain by other strides manipulation), then

```py
res = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(len(a)*len(a[0]), 3), strides=(a.strides[2], a.strides[0]))
```

might be an even better solution for you than `moveaxis/reshape`